# IKImageBrowserView thumbnail resize on reload

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-elcapitan, ikimagebrowserview

I'm using IKImageBrowserView to display a list of images, but some images are smaller than the size of the cell. At the first opening the thumbnails are ok but after a imageVersion++ and reloadData the thumbnails for the small images are resizing to the size of the cell. Another reload is fixing the issue, but I cannot find a workaround to stop this happening.

[image: first opening]

[image: after reload]